# How to solve pyOpenGL glViewport's error for PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to get 3D rendering for an app with pyqtgraph but I get an error that I do not understand. 
I'm running the script on a remote desktop (it has to run onto a remote desktop) that is not connected to internet. Hence, I installed pyqtgraph, pyopenGL and pyqt5 through .whl files (the Anaconda distribution was already installed) 
Here is a little code that should just show a blank glViewport:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt 

class Render3D(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.fen = QWidget(flags=Qt.Dialog)
        self.fen.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 800)
        self.fen.setWindowTitle("My window")

        self.disposition = QGridLayout()

        # viewport
        self.w = gl.GLViewWidget()

        self.disposition.addWidget(self.w, 0, 0)
        self.fen.setLayout(self.disposition)

        self.fen.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test = Render3D()
```

I know there is no item in my Viewport (intentionally retired because the error is from the viewport itself). I could run this script on an other computer without any error.
And here the error I get on the remote desktop :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\opengl\GLViewWidget.py", line 246, in paintGL
    glViewport(*self.getViewport())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\error.py", line 230, in glCheckError
    raise self._errorClass(
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'op\xe9ration non valide',
    baseOperation = glViewport,
    cArguments = (0, 0, 978, 778)
)
```

Do you know where the error could come from ?

Comment: try moving `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *`
`from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt` before `import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl`

Comment: @eyllanesc it just changed the cArguments value to (0, 0, 640, 480) but the error still show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the graphic card driver. I updated it and it worked!
You should check that if you encounter the same problem.